# How to create linux partitions on external drive?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning

I have a USB external hard drive with a single NTFS partition. I'd like to install Batocera and Recalbox each on a different partition, so I can boot from either of them to try both and select which one I like, while keeping the NTFS partition. And then I'd like to keep one of them and delete the other, extending the NTFS partition. How can I do this without loosing data from the hard drive?

Comment: Internal and external are the same: your OS can not see the case of your computer. What we need to know is how they are connected: Is it USB, sata, other? What you are trying to do: are you wanting to create boot devices, with an OS? (edit question to make this clear. Thanks)

Comment: Editing/resizing partitions will never be 100% safe.

Comment: Well I don't mind if it's not 100% safe as long as it's usually safe. If most times than not data gets deleted then I will install the OS to a different USB and keep the hard drive as it is.

Comment: i recommend to loop mount images which can be stored as regular files on underlaying ntfs partition. i have done this by first regular os installation, then clone the disk including partition table with dd into file, finally added the ext4 image into grub boot menu (repeat this for every os)

Comment: or even better, try virtualbox ;)